Skipping a case statement in a switch
I have a switch statement that I specially need the cases to fall through.  But have also a condition which is a bit of an edge case where I need to skip a case.  I've made it a simple visualization of the problem.
switch (bits_remaining)
{
    case 5:
        if (CallFunction())
            // process condition, skip case 4 and resume from case 3 <--- Is it possible?
        else
            // code for case 5
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 4:
        // code for case 4
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 3:
        // code for case 3
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 2:
        // code for case 2
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 1:
        // code for case 1
        [[fallthrough]];
}

Now I've looked around for similar answers, but they all seem to focus on appropriate use of break statements and allowing fall through when required, or rearranging cases.  Can't find anything on this particular issue to allow skipping of a case.
There's a couple of reasons why I'm asking.  Firstly, in C# fallthrough isn't allowed and you use a goto case X.  That seems a little ill-conceived because if you ever need a fallthrough switch, you end up with a goto after every case.  However in this particular instance, having such functionality would solve this problem for me nicely.  I could just goto case 3.
This code is a little time critical, so I don't really want to put a condition in case 4 that skips it, if the condition is encountered as 99% of the time, it won't be.
What would be an efficient way to do this?

I don't think there is an objective answer here, other than looking at code metrics of how it compiles and performs. If it was me, I'd just put in a goto. I think the use here is justified, especially when the code is performance-critical and therefore aesthetics have a low priority.

It a questionable design structurally speaking, so adding a goto won't make it much worse. ;-).

You have complex control flow, so don't add further complexity by going crazy with switches and gotos. Give the conditions descriptive names, compute their truth values and branch on that instead.

While goto might be possible, I'd probably feel that the entire thing with its fallthroughs is already a bit too messed up for my taste. From the looks of it, I'd probably make this more like a state machine -- I would loop over the switch statement, and each statement would basically set the next case to process, with a special "end" case. Along the same lines, I'd make "condition" an enum... also, in my experience, most cases that are perceived as "time critical" just lead to pointless micro-optimization.

@ChristianStieber I've simplified the above code somewhat, but it actually can't usefully be an enum as values of each case are in fact the number of bits remaining.  It's just that if I have 5 bits remaining, I need to deal with an edge case some of the time.  Also, I don't really have the time to "loop over" anything and to be fair, the code for the cases isn't hugely complex.

You can also put case labels inside the else branch of the if (CallFunction()) check. Something like this.

@IlCapitano Now I've double-checked, and I think you are right. Your solution is just less verbose than mine, but the effect is the same. Sorry for the confusion. Maybe you should post it as an answer.

You might consider using a precondition
if (condition == 5 && CallFunction()) condition = 3;
switch (condition)
{
    case 5:
        * code for case 5 *
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 4:
        * code for case 4 *
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 3:
        * code for case 3
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 2:
        * code for case 2
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 1:
        * code for case 1
        [[fallthrough]];
}


I was actually thinking along these lines myself.  Almost pre-processing the edge case so that it didn't need to be dealt with in the switch.

Just checking the assembly, it looks like the compiler is capable of optimizing a goto and a bool flag the same way. Both of the following codes generate practically identical code on GCC with -O2:
bool fun5();
void fun4();
void fun3();
void fun2();
void fun1();

void with_goto(int condition)
{
    switch(condition) {
        case 5:
            if (fun5())
                goto case3;
        case 4: fun4();
        case 3:
        case3:
            fun3();
        case 2: fun2();
        case 1: fun1();
    }
}
void with_condition(int condition)
{
    bool skip4 = false;
    switch(condition) {
        case 5:
            skip4 = fun5();
        case 4:
            if (!skip4)
                fun4();
        case 3:
            fun3();
        case 2: fun2();
        case 1: fun1();
    }
}

with_condition(int):
        cmp     edi, 5
        ja      .L26
        mov     edi, edi
        sub     rsp, 8
        jmp     [QWORD PTR .L20[0+rdi*8]]
.L20:
        .quad   .L17
        .quad   .L24
        .quad   .L23
        .quad   .L22
        .quad   .L21
        .quad   .L19
.L19:
        call    fun5()
        test    al, al
        jne     .L22
.L21:
        call    fun4()
.L22:
        call    fun3()
.L23:
        call    fun2()
.L24:
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     fun1()
.L17:
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L26:
        ret

Notice how case 4 (.L21) is not impacted by the skip4 variable.
Tested with GCC-4.1.2 and 13.2. It's a basic optimization. It should be present in any optimizing compiler. However, you need the equivalent of GCC's -O2. -O1 is insufficient.

Thanks for going to the assembly... To be fair, that's what I should have done, but I was just seeing if there was a nicer way I hadn't thought of.  Great reply.

"The" compiler?  Even specifying GCC leaves a lot of different versions out there (I'm guessing that the target ISA doesn't make a difference in this case, or it would be dozens of different compilers).

@TobySpeight Tested with GCC-4.1.2 and 13.2, if you are interested. It's a basic optimization. It should be present in any optimizing compiler. However, you need the equivalent of GCC's -O2. -O1 is insufficient.

Godbolt link for those who like to experiment.

Another possibility (but certainly neither cleaner nor nicer), if you want to avoid goto, you could create a dummy loop, which you then always exit after the first iteration, as needed:
#include <iostream>

bool CallFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Function called\n";
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int bits_remaining{ 5 };
    switch (bits_remaining)
    {
    case 5:
        for (;;)
        {
            if (CallFunction())
            {
                std::cout << "case 5, function returned true\n";
                break;
            }

            std::cout << "case 5, function returned false\n";
            [[fallthrough]];
            case 4:
                std::cout << "case 4\n";
            break;
        }
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 3:
        std::cout << "case 3\n";
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 2:
        std::cout << "case 2\n";
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 1:
        std::cout << "case 1\n";
        [[fallthrough]];
    default:
        std::cout << "default case\n";
    }
}

But, as others have already mentioned, I'd restructure the whole logic into a state machine instead.

Wow, that's pretty mental...  I'm not sure I'd go so far as having case 4 inside a loop and using break as a way to by-pass it.  That's cool though.

It is totally valid to interleave switch and if statements:
switch (bits_remaining)
{
    case 5:
        if (CallFunction())
            ** process condition, skip case 4 and resume from case 3 **  <--- Is it possible?
        else
        {
            * code for case 5 *
            [[fallthrough]];
        
    case 4:
            * code for case 4 *
        }
        [[fallthrough]];
        
    case 3:
        * code for case 3
        [[fallthrough]];
        
    case 2:
        * code for case 2
        [[fallthrough]];
        
    case 1:
        * code for case 1
        [[fallthrough]];
}


I'd argue it's less readable than some of the other answers, but a completely valid solution.

@LHLaurini I agree about the readability part. The best solution, IMO, is the one with the Evil Goto, lol.

I'd prefer to refactor that snippet into a function and use it like this:
void function(int bits_remaining)
{
    switch (bits_remaining)
    {
        case 5:
            if (CallFunction())
            {
                function(3);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                * code for case 5 *
            }
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 4:
            * code for case 4 *
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 3:
            * code for case 3
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 2:
            * code for case 2
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 1:
            * code for case 1
            [[fallthrough]];
    }
}

In C++23, you could also use a lambda (but it gets a bit more convoluted):
[](this auto self, int bits_remaining) -> void
{
    switch (bits_remaining)
    {
        case 5:
            if (CallFunction())
            {
                self(3);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                * code for case 5 *
            }
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 4:
            * code for case 4 *
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 3:
            * code for case 3
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 2:
            * code for case 2
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 1:
            * code for case 1
            [[fallthrough]];
    }
}(bits_remaining);

